# "Load" event in "events" property of Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Normally any event I can listen for in jQuery I can also listen for in Backbone.  In other words, if I have:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend();
var view = new MyView();
view.$el.html('<button>');
var onClick = function() {
    alert('woot!');
};
```

and I want to trigger `onClick` when the button is clicked, I *could* do:

```
$('button').on('click', onClick);
```

but because I'm using Backbone I'd instead do:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {click: onClick}
});
```

However, that doesn't work with the `load` event of iframes, so if I have:

```
view.$el.html('<iframe src="www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>');
var onLoad = function() {
    alert('woot!');
};
```

I can do:

```
$('iframe').on('load', onLoad);
```

but I can't do:

```
events: {load: onLoad}
```

My question is two-part: 1) why doesn't this work, and 2) is there any way to work around it, but still use Backbone's `events` instead of raw JQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The events in [`events`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) are attached using [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) and that uses the delegation form of jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). But `on` delegation [only works with events that bubble](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes):

> In all browsers, the `load`, `scroll`, and `error` events (e.g., on an `<img>` element) do not bubble. [...] Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.

So a `load` event in the `events` object won't do anything for you because `load` doesn't bubble up the DOM so it doesn't work with event delegation.

You're left with doing it manually (probably using `this.$('iframe').on` to properly isolate it to `iframe`s inside your view's `el`) or using a separate view for the `<iframe>`. The latter will work because if you don't include a selector in `events`:

```
events: {
    load: 'handler'
}
```

then the event is bound directly to the view's `el`. If you have a view like this:

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'iframe',
    attributes: {
        src: 'http://example.com'
    },
    events: {
        load: 'loaded'
    },
    loaded: function() {
        // This should get called.
    }
});
```

then the `el` will be `<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>` and the `load` event will be bound directly to that `<iframe>`. This may or may not work depending on what exactly you need the event handler to do.